# last friday of month query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I found this excellent example from @lserni on calculating the last Friday of a month.

```
SET @DATE='1962-10-20';
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(@DATE), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@DATE))+7-4))%7 DAY) AS friday;
+------------+
| friday     |
+------------+
| 1962-10-26 |
+------------+
```

**Edit:**

Based on the date supplied, give me the next Last Friday of a month (even if the date supplied)

Comment: and what if it is not?

Comment: Then give me the last Friday of that current month.

Comment: There, hopefully I set the question up for smart people to figure out :)

Comment: @AlMartin: I think he was implying that he was *not* one of the smart people, but some actual smart people would come in and answer the question (i.e., not him).

Comment: it is called self-deprecation, chill

Answer (score 0):

Based on Drew's answer I did some experimenting and found a solution that works for me.

```
SET @DATE='2015-09-26';
SELECT
    CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(@DATE), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@DATE))+7-4))%7 DAY) > @DATE
    THEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(@DATE), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@DATE))+7-4))%7 DAY)
    ELSE DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(@DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(@DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))+7-4))%7 DAY)
    END AS last_friday
```

Comment: I didn't. I tried it and it just returned the same month. But you pointed me in the right direction with using case.